# How to optimize MySQL query (group and order)

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

Hey all, I've got a query in need of optimizing. It works but its a dog, performance wise.

It reads like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    views
        WHERE   user_id = '1'
        ORDER BY
                page DESC
        ) v
GROUP BY
        v.session
```

I'm tracking views to different pages, and I want to know the highest page per session, in order to know how far they've clicked through (they're required to view every page all the way to the end) in any given session.

Basically what I'm trying to do is ORDER the results before the GROUP. Which the above achieves, at significant cost.

Anyone who can slap me over the head with how to do this? Thanks guys!

**Update:**

The Explain:

```
"1" "PRIMARY"   "<derived2>"    "ALL"   \N  \N  \N  \N  "3545"  "Using temporary; Using filesort"

"2" "DERIVED"   "views" "index" \N  "page"  "5" \N  "196168"    "Using where"
```

The schema:

```
ID       int(8) unsigned  (NULL)     NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references         
page     int(8)           (NULL)     YES     MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
user_id  int(8)           (NULL)     YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
session  int(8)           (NULL)     YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
created  datetime         (NULL)     NO                                       select,insert,update,references
```

Index Info:

```
views            0  PRIMARY              1  ID           A               196008    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE    

views            1  page                 1  page         A                  259    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE
```

Comment: When asking for mysql performance optimization please always provide the following. 1. Query 2. EXPLAIN Query output 3. SHOW CREATE TABLE for all appropriate tables. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some details on your schema?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm tracking views to different pages, and I want to know the highest page per session, in order to know how far they've clicked through (they're required to view every page all the way to the end) in any given session.

Ordering before grouping is a highly unreliable way to do this.

`MySQL` extends `GROUP BY` syntax: you can use ungrouped and unaggregated fields in `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

In this case, a random value of `page` is output per each `session`.

[**Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) explicitly states that you should never make any assumptions on which value exactly will it be:

> Do not use this feature if the columns you omit from the `GROUP BY` part are not constant in the group. The server is free to return any value from the group, so the results are indeterminate unless all values are the same.

However, in practice, the values from the first row scanned are returned.

Since you are using an `ORDER BY page DESC` in your subquery, this row happens to be the rows with a maximal `page` per session.

You shouldn't rely on it, since this behaviour is undocumented and if some other row will be returned in next version, it will not be considered a bug.

But you don't even have to do such nasty tricks.

Just use aggregate functions:

```
SELECT  MAX(page)
FROM    views
WHERE   user_id = '1'
GROUP BY
        session
```

This is documented and clean way to do what you want.

Create a composite index on `(user_id, session, page)` for the query to run faster.

If you need all columns from your table, not only the aggregated ones, use this syntax:

```
SELECT  v.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT user_id, session
        FROM    views
        ) vo
JOIN    views v
ON      v.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    views vi
        WHERE   vi.user_id = vo.user_id
                AND vi.session = vo.session
        ORDER BY
                page DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

This assumes that `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` on `views`.

Comment: `Create a composite index on (user_id, session, page) for the query to run faster.` This statament save my lots of time. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4):

I think your subquery is unnecessary. You would receive the same results from this much simpler (and faster) query:

```
SELECT *
FROM views 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
GROUP BY session
ORDER BY page DESC
```

Also, you should have an index on every field you're either grouping, ordering or "where-ing" by. In this case, you need an index on user_id, session and page.

Comment: Beat me to it - the subquery is completely unnecessary, and ORDER BY should only EVER be applied to the final SELECT statement.

Comment: The `@op` is trying to just retrieve `MAX(page)` for each session. Ordering and selecting an ungrouped and unaggregated column is a `MySQL` extension, which outputs the first `page` met in each session id. When the `GROUP BY` is applied to a subquery, this `page` happens to be the least `page` per session, which yields the `MAX(page)` in `SELECT`. Your solution is not guaranteed to return the least page first.

Comment: My query had an inner join. The field on which 2 tables were getting joined was not indexed. Adding it to index solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a composite (multi-column) index on user_id, page.  That assumes the inner query is the slow part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the subselect. SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM)

You should be using a join. What data type is your 'page' field?