# Need help constructing MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

My data & table is as follows:

```
+------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------+-------------+
| sr   | thread_id  | thread_no | client_name  | date       | time     | status      |
+------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------+-------------+
|  871 | 1281473902 |         0 | Demo Company | 2011-01-17 | 16:53:00 | Closed      |
| 1179 | 1269343346 |         0 | Demo Company | 2010-03-23 | 11:22:00 | Open        |
| 1180 | 1269343585 |         0 | Demo Company | 2010-03-23 | 11:26:00 | Closed      |
| 1181 | 1269343679 |         0 | Demo Company | 2010-03-23 | 11:27:00 | Open        |
| 1182 | 1269343835 |         0 | Demo Company | 2010-03-23 | 11:30:00 | Open        |
| 2392 | 1295285762 |         0 | Demo Company | 2011-01-17 | 17:35:00 | Closed      |
| 2393 | 1295286578 |         0 | Demo Company | 2011-01-18 | 08:01:00 | Open        |
| 2526 | 1299764352 |         0 | Demo Company | 2011-04-29 | 11:01:00 | Closed      |
| 8727 | 1299764352 |         1 | Demo Company | 2011-06-16 | 09:31:00 | Closed      |
| 8728 | 1299764352 |         2 | Demo Company | 2011-06-16 | 09:56:00 | Closed      |
| 8729 | 1299764352 |         3 | Demo Company | 2011-06-16 | 09:57:00 | Closed      |
| 8731 | 1308234742 |         0 | Demo Company | 2011-06-16 | 10:31:00 | Open        |
| 8734 | 1308236479 |         0 | Demo Company | 2011-06-16 | 11:00:00 | Open-Urgent |
| 8735 | 1308236519 |         0 | Demo Company | 2011-06-16 | 11:01:00 | On Hold     |
| 8736 | 1308236519 |         1 | Demo Company | 2011-06-16 | 11:02:00 | Closed      |
| 8740 | 1308242129 |         0 | Demo Company | 2011-06-16 | 12:34:00 | Closed      |
| 8796 | 1308242129 |         1 | Demo Company | 2011-06-24 | 06:27:00 | Closed      |
| 8798 | 1308242129 |         2 | Demo Company | 2011-06-24 | 07:43:00 | Open        |
| 8799 | 1308242129 |         3 | Demo Company | 2011-06-24 | 07:44:00 | Open        |
+------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

I need to select ROWS with DISTINCT thread_id and having the highest value of thread_no for that distinct thread_id

For example, for thread_id 1299764352, I need to select the row with sr=8729

The closes I could come to was with this query:

```
SELECT sr, thread_id, max(thread_no) as thread_no, client_name, date, time, status 
    FROM table 
    group by thread_id 
    order by sr
```

But this query gives me the row with thread_no=0 and not the row with highest value of thread_no

I hope I was able to explain well.

Please help.

Thx
Vai

Answer (score 5):

I guess the following query is what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM table AS b 
WHERE b.thread_id = a.thread_id AND b.thread_no > a.thread_no )
```

Comment: you can make your code look like code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` button.

Comment: So wouldn't you be so kind to approve my answer ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
GROUP BY thread_id 
ORDER BY MAX(thread_no) DESC, sr ASC
```

Comment: solution provided by @Grigor Gevorgyan worked perfect. Thx @Grigor Gevorgyan

Comment: @vai: Whichever solution works for you. Check if it works in the first place, then check for speed differences. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for the analytic function '**partition by**'.
See [this](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag) article.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM myTable AS m
  JOIN
    ( SELECT thread_id
           , MAX(thread_no) AS max_no
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY thread_id
    ) AS grp
    ON m.thread_id = grp.thread_id
    AND m.thread_no = grp.max_no
```

or like this (credits to **[Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201296/how-to-optimize-mysql-query-group-and-order/1201365#1201365)**):

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT thread_id
      FROM myTable
    ) AS md
  JOIN myTable AS m
    ON m.sr =
      ( SELECT mi.sr
        FROM myTable mi
        WHERE mi.thread_id = md.thread_id
        ORDER BY mi.thread_no DESC
        LIMIT 1
      )
```