# MySQL join or subquery - get product data along with first product image

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'd like to be able to return a thumbnail (first image of a set) with my product data - what is the best way to accomplish this (performance)?

I have the following tables:

**products** (product data)
**products_images** (relation between products and images)
**images** (image data)

So for every product, it'd return the first image of a set associated with that product.

Two things:

- I'm trying to get the first image but the order depends on an 'order'
  field.
- If no image found just return null for image data but still
  get product.

I'm thinking of doing a subquery since I don't know how to about ordering and limiting image results in a join.

What do you suggest?

**Edit:**

The image order field is present in the **products_images** table. That table has the following fields (product_id, image_id, order)

Comment: On which table is the `order` field? `products_images` or `images`? In fact, can you please just post the full create table definitions (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ....`)?

Comment: @Mark - I currently don't have access to the schema but I know the order field is present in the prodcuts_images table. Let me know if you need any more information. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    p.*
  , i.thumbnail
FROM 
    products AS p
  LEFT JOIN
    images AS i
      ON i.image_id =
         ( SELECT image_id
           FROM products_images AS pi
           WHERE pi.product_id = p.product_id
           ORDER BY `order` ASC                      --- or DESC
           LIMIT 1
         )
```

An index on `(product_id, order, image_id)` in table `products_images` would be useful for the subquery to run faster.

Comment: The framework I'm using (CodeIgniter) keeps trying to escape the SELECT in the JOIN and breaks the query - before I go ahead and switch over my query to pure SQL, is there another way to do this without losing performance? (putting in the SELECT or something like that?) Cheers

Comment: @RS7: Have you removed the `--- or DESC` part? That is just a comment (perhaps it confuses CodeIgniter?)

Comment: If you mean how to translate this query in terms of CodeIgniter, I don't know if that is possible (with the unusual `ON table.field = (SELECT...)` condition). Perhaps you can ask another question.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it before - I'm currently using CodeIgniter's Active Record library. It seems that its join() function tries to incorrectly protect field/table names and ends up adding back ticks to the SELECT in the subquery. I was asking about possibly moving the JOIN portion, since I believe subqueries anywhere else aren't affected. (I did remove the --- or DESC) Cheers

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ im wondering why are you using that particular index order `(product_id, order, image_id)` instead of `(image_id, product_id, order)`, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @AndresSK the query is doing a "LATERAL" join (also called CROSS APPLY in other product, e.g. SQL Server). So, for every product, it tried to find one image (the latest). So the plan will usually be a nested loop, an iteration per product. That's why I put the product_id first (the column in WHERE) the `order` second (the column in ORDER BY) and the image_id last (the column in SELECT). (I mean the WHERE-ORDER BY-SELECT in the subquery)) You can try it with some (not too small) tables, say 10-50K products and 100K - 1M rows in products_images, and test the performance with various indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the first image by the `order` column in the product_images table:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pi.product_id, i.*
    FROM images i
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT product_id, image_id
        FROM products_images pi
        ORDER BY `order`        
    ) pi ON i.image_id = i.id
    GROUP BY product_id
) i ON i.product_id = p.id
```

Comment: See Quassnoi's answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201296/how-to-optimize-mysql-query-group-and-order/1201365#1201365 on why you should not be doing this (Order by in a subquery - then Group by in the query).